# Error while issuing ping command inside monkeyrunner script

Tags: adb, python-2.7, monkeyrunner, android-sdk-1.6, jython-2.5

i am facing some issues in device.shell('ping -c 2 192.168.1.1') inside a monkeyrunner script.
Its throwing below error:-
120202 20:12:17.192:S [main] [com.android.chimpchat.adb.AdbChimpDevice] Error executing command: ping -c 2 192.168.1.1

```
while (count<1000) :
device.shell('dmesg -c')
print '****swithing OFF wifi in loop NO-',count
device.touch(400,155,MonkeyDevice.DOWN_AND_UP)
time.sleep(10)
print '****switching ON wifi in loop NO-',count
device.touch(400,155,MonkeyDevice.DOWN_AND_UP)
time.sleep(25)
fd=open('pingstats.txt','a+b')
fd.write('***Loop-%i \n************\n%s\n****************\n' % (int(count),ping))
ping = device.shell('ping -c 2 192.168.1.1')
status=re.search('unreachable',ping)
if status:
    dmesg=device.shell('dmesg')
    fd.write(logcat)
fd.close()
count = count + 1
```

please see above script...
Someone please help....

Comment: Hard to tell but that's often file not found, ie your script can't see ping. Try putting a full path to it, or check the environment within the script

Comment: hi tony,i have changed the shell command,it is returning same error after some time.Begning it is working ,after some time it is crashing......


    120207 17:20:29.223:S [main] [com.android.chimpchat.adb.AdbChimpDevice] Error executing command: wl ver
120207 17:20:29.223:S [main] [com.android.chimpchat.adb.AdbChimpDevice]com.android.ddmlib.ShellCommandUnresponsiveException

Comment: Maybe someelse will comalong, don'y know much about monkey runner, comment was just based on number of other environments I've used. Worth putting your count in the log file, see if it's stopping about the "same time". Also some sort of error trap, sleep try again later?